# is it grammatical and idiomatic to add a "the" before an "ordinal number"?

Tags: word-usage

this lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/4IAXaixaLWE)

> Hello everyone. Welcome to the second lecture for CS230.

is it grammatical and idiomatic to add a "the" before an "ordinal number"?

Comment: In that sentence it is. You couldn't say *welcome to second lecture* - it would have to be *welcome to lecture two of CS230*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

agree with @Minty, this case needs "the" before an "ordinal number", it would have to be `welcome to lecture two of CS230`.

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence

> Welcome to the second lecture for CS230.

the definite article "the" is not only permitted but  required. Some other uses also use the definite article, such as:

> - The Fifth Legion was stationed in what is now Germany.
> - The Fourth Horseman of the Apocalypse is Death.
> - The second book of the Torah is Exodus.
> - The Twentieth volume of O'Brian's series is *Blue at the Mizzen*.
> - The Fourth of July is a holiday in the united States, while the Fifth of November is celebrated in the United Kingdom.
> - The third chapter of the novel is the most exciting one.
> - I enjoyed the start, but when i reached the fifth chapter, I lost interest.
> - In "Sir Patrick Spens" I clean forgot the twenty-seventh verse, so I sang the forty-second twice as loud and in reverse, and no one noticed.
> - Hownblower's ship *The Sutherland* was a third-rate.

However some other uses of ordinals do not take articles.

> - Jones has won second place in today's race.
> - Second place goes to Jones.
> - It is good practice to design a database in fifth normal form.
> - Ballet dancers often speak of second and third position.
> - I shifted into third gear.
> - This restaurant is first-rate.

I can't clearly identify a general rule indicating when n article (definite or indefinite) is required, or customary in such uses.